# Any idea how to fix group.leave() crash report error in dispatch group ('dispatch_group_leave$VARIANT$mp.cold.1 + 36')?

Tags: swift, xcode, concurrency, crashlytics, dispatchgroup

My iOS app in Xcode calls the following method both on app launch and then every 10 minutes. Although I can't reproduce the crash, Crashlytics has it crashing regularly around 'group.leave()', or when each submission task is leaving the dispatch group. Any ideas what could cause it?

My thoughts:

1. dispatch group enter/leaves are unbalanced. could be the result of completion closure returning multiple times, but I don' think that's happening
2. race conditions - maybe other parts of the app are trying to access the same data causing invalidations etc. would using a dispatch semaphore help with this?

Below is the code and stack trace. TIA!

Crashing method:

```swift
class func checkForSubmissionsToUpload(onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void){
        let realm = Utils.getRealm()
        if let uploadSubmissions = realm?.objects(STLocalSubmission.self).filter("needsUpload = %@", true) {
            if uploadSubmissions.count == 0 {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                
                let group = DispatchGroup()
               
                for submission in uploadSubmissions{
           
                    let isValidSubmission = !submission.isInvalidated
                    if isValidSubmission, let form = submission.formObject, let projectID = submission.projectID.value {
                        group.enter()
                        
                        submitSubmission(
                            submission,
                            form: form,
                            projectID: projectID,
                            draft: submission.draft,
                            completion: { (response) in
                                
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                                    group.leave()
                                    
                                    if let error = response?["error"] as? Bool, let message = APIManager.messageFrom(dictionary: response) {
                                        if error {
                                            print("error: \(message)")
                                            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: message)//.showAlert(withTitle: "Error.", andMessage: message)
                                            
                                            return
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (response == nil || response!.count <= 1) {
                                        if let extraErrors = response?["extraErrors"] as? [Any], let message = extraErrors.first as? String {
                                            print("error: \(message)")
                                            //                            self.showAlert(withTitle: "Error.", andMessage: message)
                                            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: message)
                                            
                                            return
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                    
                                    if let submissionID = response?["submission_id"] as? Int ?? Int(submission.id) {
                                        let serverSubmission = STServerSubmission(id: submissionID,
                                                                                  submission: submission)
                                        
                                        // add the submission data to realm
                                        let realm = Utils.getRealm()
                                        try? realm?.write {
                                            
                                            realm?.delete(submission)
                                            realm?.add(serverSubmission, update: .all)
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        
                                        print("error - no submission id returned after submitting form data")
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                    }
                }
                group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                    
                    onSuccess()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

Including 'submitSubmission', which then calls 'request':

```swift
class func submitSubmission(_ submission: STLocalSubmission, form: STForm, projectID: Int, draft: Bool, completion: @escaping ([AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void) {
    
    var fields = [[String : Any?]]()
    var approvalUserID = [Int?]()
    
    if (form.isInvalidated || submission.isInvalidated) { return }
    submission.uploadAllImages() {
        response in
        
        if response == false {
            print("error submitting submission")
            
            var errors = [String : Any]()
            errors["error"] = true
            errors["message"] = "Error uploading images"
            completion(errors)
            return
        }
        
        for row in submission.dataRows {
            if (row.isInvalidated) { continue }
            let rowObject = form.rowByTag(row.intTag)
            
            if rowObject != nil {
                if !draft {
                    
                    // only perform data validation if it is not a draft
                    if rowObject?.required == true && row.serverValue == nil {
                        
                        print("error submitting submission - no row server value for required row \(rowObject?.tag ?? 0)")
                        
                        var errors = [String : Any]()
                        errors["error"] = true
                        
                        if let title = rowObject?.title,
                           let formID = submission.formID.value,
                           let formVersionId = submission.formVersionID.value {
                            errors["message"] = "\nIncomplete Form.\nThe following field is required: \n\n \(title) \n\nForm ID: \(formID) \nForm Version ID: \(formVersionId)"
                        }
                        completion(errors)
                        return
                    }
                }
                
                var field = [String : Any?]()
                field["id"] = row.intTag
                field["label"] = rowObject?.title
                
                print("row title = \(rowObject?.title) value = \(row.serverValue)")
                
                if rowObject?.multiple ?? true{
                    
                    if row.serverValue is [Any]{
                        field["value"] = row.serverValue
                    }else{
                        var array = [Any?]()
                        array.append(row.serverValue)
                        
                        field["value"] = array
                    }
                    
                }else{
                    field["value"] = row.serverValue
                }
                
                field["required"] = rowObject?.required
                
                if rowObject?.type == .register {
                    
                    var array = ""
                    if row.registerSignIns.count != 0 {
                        let selectedUsers = row.registerSignIns
                        for user in selectedUsers {
                            if user.id != "" {
                                if array == "" {
                                    array = "\(user.id)"
                                } else {
                                    array = array + ",\(user.id)"
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                        field["value"] = array
                    }
                }
                
                //check if array contains field for that id already and append the value part
                if rowObject?.multiple ?? true {
                    var existCount = 0
                    for index in 0..<fields.count {
                        
                        if fields[index]["id"] as? Int == row.intTag{
                            if (fields[index]["value"] as? [Any?]) != nil{
                                
                                fields[index]["value"] = row.serverValue
                            }
                        }else{
                            existCount += 1
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    if existCount == fields.count {
                        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: field, options: [])
                        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
                        print(jsonString ?? 0)
                        fields.append(field)
                    }
                } else{
                    fields.append(field)
                }
            }
        }
        
        for approversID in submission.selectedUsers {
            approvalUserID.append(approversID.id)
        }
        
        
        let parameters: [String : Any] = [ "fields" : fields,
                                           "project_id" : projectID,
                                           "draft" : draft,
                                           "approval_users" : approvalUserID]
        
        var stringId: String? = nil
        
        if submission.isNewForm, let id = submission.formVersionID.value {
            stringId = String(id)
        }
        else {
            stringId = submission.id
        }
        guard let unwrappedID = stringId else {
            print("error - submission has no id!")
            return
        }
        
        let target = submission.isNewForm ? "forms" : "submissions"
        APIManager.request(to: "api/\(target)/\(unwrappedID)/submit",
                           parameters: parameters,
                           needsAuthToken: true,
                           post: true,
                           completion: completion)
    }
}


private class func request(to path: String,
                           parameters: [String: Any],
                           needsAuthToken: Bool, post: Bool,
                           completion: @escaping ([AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void) {
    
    // always set the apitoken in the URL, whether it's a GET or POST request
    var getParameters: [String : Any]?
    var postParameters: [String : Any]?
    
    if post {
        getParameters = [String : Any]()
        postParameters = parameters
    } else {
        getParameters = parameters
    }
    
    if needsAuthToken {
        guard let authToken = FXKeychain.default().object(forKey: "authToken") as? String else {
            print("error with request to path: \(path) - no auth token")
            FXKeychain.default().removeObject(forKey: "loggedIn")
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Install+Login", bundle: nil)
            var viewController: UIViewController? = nil
            if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "installCode") == nil {
                viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InstallCodeVC")
            } else {
                viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
            }
            UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController = viewController
            UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.makeKeyAndVisible()
            return
        }
        getParameters!["api_token"] = authToken
        // print("Auth Token \(authToken)")
    } else {
        getParameters!["api_token"] = apiToken
    }
    
    // add code to completion closure. log out when returns unauthorised
    let finalCompletion: ([AnyHashable : Any]?) -> (Void) = {
        response in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let extraErrors = response?["extraErrors"] as? [Any] {
                for object in extraErrors {
                    if let message = object as? String {
                        if message.contains("HTTP Status Code: 401") {
                            // log user out
                            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                            FXKeychain.default().removeObject(forKey: "authToken")
                            FXKeychain.default().removeObject(forKey: "userID")
                            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
                            var viewController: UIViewController? = nil
                            viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC")
                            UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController = viewController
                            UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.makeKeyAndVisible()
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            completion(response)
        }
    }
    
    print("API Request = \(path) - Params = \(getParameters)")
    

    if path == "check-install-code" {
        STNetworkManager.request(toURL: baseURLString + path, withGetParameters: getParameters, postParameters: postParameters, completion: finalCompletion)
    } else {
        STNetworkManager.request(toURL: ((UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "baseUrl") as? String ?? nil) ?? baseURLString) + path, withGetParameters: getParameters, postParameters: postParameters, completion: finalCompletion)
    }
}
```

Crashlytics stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x689fc dispatch_group_leave$VARIANT$mp.cold.1 + 36
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x4d5c _dispatch_group_wake + 138
2  SitePlex                       0xfc3f8 closure #1 in closure #1 in static APIManager.checkForSubmissionsToUpload(onSuccess:) + 1683 (APIManager.swift:1683)
3  SitePlex                       0xf1a8c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4299774604 (<compiler-generated>:4299774604)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x637a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x64780 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x10bdc _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1082c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 36
8  CoreFoundation                 0x91a2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
9  CoreFoundation                 0x756c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2080
10 CoreFoundation                 0x79da0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
11 GraphicsServices               0x1998 GSEventRunModal + 160
12 UIKitCore                      0x37180c -[UIApplication _run] + 868
13 UIKitCore                      0x371484 UIApplicationMain + 312
14 SitePlex                       0x880c main + 15 (AppDelegate.swift:15)
15 ???                            0x1d2f90344 (Missing)

com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1030 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12b18 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12db8 mach_msg_overwrite + 484
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1524 mach_msg + 20
4  CoreFoundation                 0x741c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
5  CoreFoundation                 0x75360 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x79da0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
7  Foundation                     0x3e138 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 208
8  Foundation                     0x3e034 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 60
9  UIKitCore                      0x493cd8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 404
10 Foundation                     0x55c9c __NSThread__start__ + 704
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x30ec _pthread_start + 116
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x172c thread_start + 8

Realm notification listener
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2800 kevent + 8
1  Realm                          0x39c6d8 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() + 156
2  Realm                          0x39c828 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct>>, realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0>>(void*) + 52
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x30ec _pthread_start + 116
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x172c thread_start + 8

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
0  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1a4e4 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 184
1  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1a8c4 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1176
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x14250 FIRCLSHandler + 48
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x16bc8 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 1248
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x30ec _pthread_start + 116
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x172c thread_start + 8

com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1030 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12b18 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12db8 mach_msg_overwrite + 484
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1524 mach_msg + 20
4  CoreFoundation                 0x741c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
5  CoreFoundation                 0x75360 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x79da0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
7  CoreFoundation                 0xb8c58 CFRunLoopRun + 60
8  CoreMotion                     0x12fac CLMotionActivity::isTypeInVehicle(CLMotionActivity::Type) + 23288
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x30ec _pthread_start + 116
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x172c thread_start + 8

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1030 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12b18 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12db8 mach_msg_overwrite + 484
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1524 mach_msg + 20
4  CoreFoundation                 0x741c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
5  CoreFoundation                 0x75360 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x79da0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
7  CFNetwork                      0x228520 _CFURLStorageSessionDisableCache + 50860
8  Foundation                     0x55c9c __NSThread__start__ + 704
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x30ec _pthread_start + 116
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x172c thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14f0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1c1c _pthread_wqthread + 360
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1720 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14f0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1c1c _pthread_wqthread + 360
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1720 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14f0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1c1c _pthread_wqthread + 360
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1720 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1718 start_wqthread + 270

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x14f0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1c1c _pthread_wqthread + 360
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1720 start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: Could you share `submitSubmission` to see if there is no `completion` called multiple times indeed? You also `leave()` before processing the response?

Comment: Unrelated but you should prefer `isEmpty` over `count == 0` and `guard let` might make your code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks - I've added submitSubmission and also request (called by submitSubmission), this goes on to call another method that eventually makes the request. Would leaving before processing response cause the error? My assumption was that the processing (basically error handling + realm writes) could take place independently of the synchronised group of network calls - basically as long as each submission is submitted to the api we can move forward regardless of response

Comment: Just migrate to Concurrency

Comment: Usually if you get an error on `leave`, it happens if `leave` was called more times than `enter`. So things to look for include might include any “retry” logic buried in `STNetworkManager`. Or look in `STNetworkManager` and see if there is any path of execution where you call `completion`, but neglect to immediately return. Another (less common) thing to look for is whether you’ve got any code that saves a completion handler parameter in some property that you neglect to nil.

Comment: By the way, unrelated to your current problem, but you do have the opposite problem, namely paths of execution where you fail to call the completion handler. Again, failing to call the completion handler will not cause the crash you described, but nonetheless, you must make sure that every path of execution calls the completion handler exactly once and only once.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will investigate this further

Comment: If you’re having trouble reproducing the error, test some edge cases, such invalid credentials, turn off network right before this call, try network link conditioner to simulate bad network connectivity, etc. We tend to focus our testing with the “happy path”, so try a few of the likely edge cases. As a worst case scenario, consider uploading a build where you do additional Crashlytics logging (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios) so you can narrow down re which network request is causing the crash, etc.